# Why do copied and pasted SSRS Expressions change?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am seeing a strange behavior in Visual Studio 2008 when creating SSRS reports.  It is happening when I copy the contents of one Text Box (Tablix Cell) and paste into another Text Box.  Any copied expressions change to give the fully qualified name of each function called.  The functions are still correct, but unsightly.

Why is this happening and is there a way to prevent it?  I am constantly copying and pasting expressions and the fully qualified names can make even simple expressions difficult for other developers to read and understand.

---

### For Example:

**Original Expression:**

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!MyField.Value), 0, Fields!MyField.Value)
```

**Copied and Pasted Expression:**

```
=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIF(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.ISNOTHING(Fields!MyField.Value), 0, Fields!MyField.Value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even i have faced the same issue and i researched about it then i found the below link that it is a bug in microsoft itself.
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/757358/pasting-objects-with-expressions-pastes-fully-qualified-functions

Comment: connect.microsoft.com links are all dead now